# SQL Where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I build a filter on a date field in using a time interval

```
Where Data is in ]date1, date2] and [date3, date4[
```

Comment: First, reduce it to the intersection of the intervals, since a date can't be in two disjoint intervals.

Comment: @Ted: We don't know that the ranges `[date1:date2]` and `[date3:date4]` are disjoint...if they are, though, your observation is correct.

Comment: The notation with the square brackets shown is not a convention I've seen.  Is it some variation on the open-closed ranges which I normally see shown as one of `[...]`, `(...)`, `[...)` or `(...]`?  Or can you clarify.  Also, are the date ranges disjoint, or can they be overlapping?  If they are disjoint, you need to use OR instead of AND; if they overlap, then you should work out the overlapping range and then use a single test for the overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT "column_name"
FROM "table_name"
WHERE "column_name" BETWEEN 'value1' AND 'value2'
```

with valid dates:

```
 where date between '2005-01-01' and '2005-01-31'
```

Comment: Those are invalid MySql Dates